# How to resize an image in web page?

Tags: html, css, firebase

I have retrieved image URL from firebase database but when i am trying to display the image retrieved on web page the size of image is not getting adjusted according to specification which i have provided in  tag in body.The image obtained is covering entire background of web page.

**JS**

```
var myParam=location.search.split('itemKey=')[1];
alert(myParam);
firebase.database().ref('/Sell_Products/'+myParam).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{var name=snapshot.child('name').val();
alert(name);
var image=snapshot.child('image').val();
var category=snapshot.child('category').val();
var description=snapshot.child('description').val();
var price=snapshot.child('price').val();
document.querySelector('img').src = image;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img height="125" width="125"/>
```

Comment: What's the html for your image?

Comment: html for image is <img height="125" width="125"/> i have checked others answers on stackoverflow and tried same but it didnt worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this: `<img style="height: 125px; width: 125px;"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.But it didn't worked out

Answer (score 0):

You can modify height and width in javascript.

1. In your html file, add `id` to your image tag like this  `<img id="my_image"/>`
2. In your javascript file, add 
   `var image = document.getElementById('my_image');`
   `image.height = '125';`
   `image.width = '125';`